# How to prove the existence of such a map and such a function

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

This question was in my manifolds notes which I borrowed from a senior and I was unable to  prove the result.

> Let S be an k-dimensional submanifold of an n-manifold M with k<n. Show that , for every point $p\in S$, there exists an open set $U\subset M$ containing p, and a smooth function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ such that $f^{-1}(0) =U \cap S$.

For every $p\in S$ there will always exists an open set $U \in M$ containing p but I have to find a specific U that also satisfies the condition on the smooth function.

A subset S of M is called a k-dimensional submanifold of M if the following holds: If $p\in S$ there exists a chart $(U,\phi)$ containing P st $\phi(U\cap S)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

But How to use it to find such a function. I am really sorry but I am unable any way to prove it. I couldn't add much to my attempt and thoughts because I am struck. Kindly don't close this question.

Please shed some light on this!

Comment: Are you familiar with the implicit function theorem?

Comment: @Jose27 Yes I am

Comment: @Jose27 Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: Coarsely: Take an adapted chart for which $S\cap U = \{(x^1,\ldots,x^n) \in U \mid x^{k+1}=\ldots=x^{n} = 0\}$ and consider the function $f(x^1,\ldots,x^n) = (x^{k+1},\ldots,x^{n})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S$ is a $k$ dimensional submanifold of the $n$ dimensional manifold $M$, for any $p\in S$, there exists an open subset $U \ni p \subset M$ and a chart $\phi\colon U \to V\subset \Bbb R^n$ (with $V$ open) such that $\phi(U\cap S) = V \cap (\Bbb R^k \times \{0\}^{n-k})$. Consider the linear projection $\pi\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^{n-k}$ defined by $\pi(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = (x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n)$, and define $f \colon U \to \Bbb R^{n-k}$ by $f = \pi\circ \phi$. Then $f$ is a solution.

The existence of such a chart is *exactly* the definition you gave. The embedding $\Bbb R^k \subset \Bbb R^n$ isn't explicit in your definition, but it surely is of the form $\Bbb R^k\times \{0\}^{n-k} \subset \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Kindly prove the existence of such a chart $\phi$ mentioned in the second line of your answer.

Comment: @No-One The definition of submanifold you provided seems to be a bit handcrafted. Could you please state the detailed one which is given in your lecture notes?

Comment: Here is the definition in the notes : A subset $ S\subset M $ is a k-dimensional submanifold of M if the following holds If $p \in S $, there is a chart $( U, \phi) $ containing p such that $\phi( U \cap S)$ is an open subset of $ \mathbb{R}^k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ .

Comment: I added an edit about the chart, but it is exactly the definition you gave. Just write it down.

Comment: @No-One Have you tried to write it down?